# Unable to reuse jdbc connection after rollback

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am using a simple JDBC program in my application of inserting some data into oracle table. It's working fine with the positive scenario, but not working in negative condition and I have disable constraint issues while exception occurs.

Below is some snippet of my code which is called from main class.

```
try{
    Connection conn=getConnection();
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    loadDataContent(conn, disabledConstraints);
    conn.commit();

}catch(Exception e){
    if(conn !=null){
        conn.rollback();
    }

    throw e;
}finally{
    DatabaseUtil.closeDatabaseConnections(conn);

}
```

I'm having issues in the below code while any exception occurs.

```
private static void loadDataContent(Connection conn,
            Map<String, String> disabledConstraints) throws SQLException,Exception {
    try{
        disabledConstraints = DataAccess.disableAllConstraints(conn);
        DataAccess.insertDataToTables(conn);
        DataAccess.enableConstraints(conn, disabledConstraints);// getting Exception
    }catch(Exception e){
        if(conn !=null){
            conn.rollback();
            try{
                if(disabledConstraints != null)
                    DataAccess.enableConstraints(conn, disabledConstraints);//getting same Exception in this line after rollback 
            }catch(Exception exception){
                log.fatal("Exception occured while enabling constraints: " + disabledConstraints);
            }
        }
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I am not able to call `DataAccess.enableConstraints` in exception condition and it has disabled all constraints. The code written in catch block after rollback is not working. Why the below code giving the same exception that getting it before rollback.

```
if(disabledConstraints != null)
   DataAccess.enableConstraints(conn, disabledConstraints);//getting same Exception in this line after rollback
```

The exception I get is **ORA-02298: cannot validate - parent keys not found**

I need a suggestion about what I am doing wrong.

Comment: it seems your inserted data violate a foreign-key-constraint

Comment: @Chris Yes I know that inserted data violate foreign-key-constraint but its not a issue. Issue is after rollback I am not able to reuse jdbc connection.

Comment: @neerja bharti: ahh ok. now i got it. does your `DataAccess.disableAllConstraints(conn);`commit the connection? and/or `DataAccess.insertDataToTables(conn);`?

Comment: @Chris No. the method  ```DataAccess.disableAllConstraints(conn)```  doesn't have commit the connection as the main class have commit. see the first block of code.

Comment: @neerja bharti: DDL-statements commit the connection implicitly. so if one constraint can be enabled, the connection gets committed. lets say the first constraint can be enabled and enablement of the second one fails, the connection is committed and `rollback()` doesnt delete inserted data

Comment: @Chris I am not getting your point so you are telling that insert statement  ``` DataAccess.insertDataToTables(conn) ``` is not rollbacked so  ```DataAccess.enableConstraints(..)``` will not work in catch condition after connection rollback because insert statement is already committed.

Comment: yes. that's it. please also take a look at [Oracle Docs - Part II - 3.3 How Oracle Database Processes DDL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgsql/sql-processing.html#GUID-14D902DA-5CAC-4892-BE8B-880A4F8A6914) the last point in the listing "Issue a COMMIT if the DDL statement succeeded or a ROLLBACK if it did not".

Comment: @Chris Let me check this then I will provide you an update on this.

Comment: alright. please do so

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your reply yaa its true as you said . Is there any other way to do it.